# Search strings between two files

Tags: text-processing, solaris

I have a two files, file1 and file2.

In file1 contents are:

```
ABC_DEC_EDC=ON
WER_QSD_RCS=ON
```

file2 contents are:

```
TRD_OIY_REC=ON
YUH_PON_UYT=ON
WER_QSD_RCS=OFF
```

I have to check line by line in file2.

**First**

`if ABC_DEC_EDC=ON` is not present in file2 then add to file2.

**Second**

In first file `SAX_IUY_TRE=OFF` is there with `OFF` but in file2 `SAX_IUY_TRE=ON` with `ON`; In this case I just want to update as with the file only `OFF`.

Example: `SAX_IUY_TRE=OFF`

All updates new updates happen in file2 only.

Output should be:

```
ABC_DEC_EDC=ON
WER_QSD_RCS=ON
    WER_RTC_YTC=ON
WER_QSD_RCS=OFF
```

Comment: output should be : 
1)ABC_DEC_EDC=ON
2)WER_QSD_RCS=ON
3)ZXC_POY_YTR=OFF
4)ZXC_OPI_GHF=ON
5)SAX_IUY_TRE=OFF
6)TRD_OIY_REC=ON
7)YUH_PON_UYT=ON
8)RTF_CDE_QWE=OFF
9)TYF_QWE_UTC=OFF
10)WER_RTC_YTC=ON
11)WER_QSD_RCS=OFF

Comment: format your question and show your `awk --version` (first line)

Comment: Does your line including lines like `1)`, `2)` or those are just for clarification? What about the numbers in output? And what happened for spaces in line3,5 in file1 and 7 infile2?

Comment: Numbers are  given in a file1 and file2  for just clarification only . Same as in output as well for clarification only. Please ignore the spaces . Its typo

Comment: last question/clarification: What about line `WER_QSD_RCS=OFF`? Where it's same in both files but different value ON/OFF? and what about if this line `ABC_DEC_EDC=OFF` exist in file2 with OFF status? Basically you want take ON/OFF from file1 if it's match `.....=` part in file2? right?

Comment: Yes correct  , if first part is same on file1 and file2 in that case update second part .

Comment: Your didn't say **how** update? according to the `ON/OFF` status in file1? Would you please update v your question with these details thanks

Answer (score 0):

It can be made in bash.

```
#! /bin/bash
file1="/tmp/output1.txt"
file2="/tmp/livefile1.txt"
cat $file1 | while read LINE; do
    KEY=${LINE%=*}
    CURRENT=$(grep $KEY= $file2)
    if [ -z "$CURRENT" ]; then  # if $CURRENT is empty
        echo NOT found $KEY in $file2, add it
        echo $LINE >> $file2
    else
        if [ "$LINE" != "$CURRENT" ]; then
            echo Found $KEY in $file2 and state has changed
            sed -i -e "s/^$KEY=.*\$/$LINE/" $file2
        fi
    fi
done
```

And run the command:

```
./update.bash
```

Output to screen:

```
NOT found ABC_DEC_EDC in /tmp/livefile1.txt, add it
Found WER_QSD_RCS in /tmp/livefile1.txt and state has changed
NOT found ZXC_POY_YTR in /tmp/livefile1.txt, add it
NOT found ZXC_OPI_GHF in /tmp/livefile1.txt, add it
Found SAX_IUY_TRE in /tmp/livefile1.txt and state has changed
```

The script read all lines from `$file1`. KEY is set to the part before `=` which is the key. Then `grep` search for the key in `$file2` and add if not found. If the key is found, then it checked if the state has changed, and update it with `sed` if it has changed.

**Edit:** Changed to look more like the questionnaire will use it.

Comment: REPLY%=* what is this and how it works ? I tried to execute this and script never ended after 10 mins also .#!/bin/bash
file1="/tmp/output1.txt"
file2="/tmp/livefile1.txt"
while read; do
    KEY=${REPLY%=*}
    if ! grep -q $KEY $file2; then
        # NOT found $KEY in file2, add it
        echo $REPLY >> $file2
    else
        # found $KEY in file2, has state changed?
        if ! grep -q $REPLY $file2; then
            # State has changed
            sed -i -e "s/^$KEY=.*\$/$REPLY/" $file2
        fi
    fi
done

Answer (score 0):

`sh` implementation.

```
#!/bin/sh

while read -r LINE
do
    setting=$(echo $LINE | sed 's/=.*//')
    switch=$(echo $LINE | sed 's/.*=//')

    found=$(grep "$setting" file2)
    if [ -z "$found" ]
    then
        echo $LINE >> file2
    else
        if [ "$switch" != "$(echo $found | sed 's/.*=//')" ]
        then
            sed -i "s/\($setting\).*/\1=$switch/" file2
        fi
    fi
done < file1
```

The script will flip the value of the settings found on both files that do not match.

Comment: I Tried this.Output is TRD_OIY_REC=ON YUH_PON_UYT=ON     RTF_CDE_QWE=OFF
TYF_QWE_UTC=OFF
WER_RTC_YTC=ON
SAX_IUY_TRE=ON
WER_QSD_RCS=OFF
TRD_OIY_REC=ON
YUH_PON_UYT=ON
RTF_CDE_QWE=OFF
TYF_QWE_UTC=OFF
WER_RTC_YTC=ON
SAX_IUY_TRE=ON
WER_QSD_RCS=OFF
TRD_OIY_REC=ON
YUH_PON_UYT=ON
RTF_CDE_QWE=OFF
TYF_QWE_UTC=OFF
WER_RTC_YTC=ON
SAX_IUY_TRE=ON
WER_QSD_RCS=OFF
TRD_OIY_REC=ON
YUH_PON_UYT=ON
RTF_CDE_QWE=OFF
TYF_QWE_UTC=OFF
WER_RTC_YTC=ON
SAX_IUY_TRE=ON
WER_QSD_RCS=OFF
TRD_OIY_REC=ON
YUH_PON_UYT=ON
RTF_CDE_QWE=OFF
TYF_QWE_UTC=OFF
WER_RTC_YTC=ON
SAX_IUY_TRE=ON
WER_QSD_RCS=OFF

Comment: #!/bin/sh
file1="/tmp/output1.txt"
file2="/tmp/livefile1.txt"

while read LINE
do
    setting=$`(echo $LINE | sed 's/=.*//')`
    switch=$`(echo $LINE | sed 's/.*=//')`

    found=$`(grep "$setting" $file2)`
    if [ -z "$found" ]
    then
        echo $LINE >> $file2
    else
        if [ "$switch" != "$(echo $found | sed 's/.*=//')" ]
        then
            sed "s/\($setting\).*/\1=$switch/" $file2
        fi
    fi
done < $file1

Comment: Output is : just printing the file2 content

Comment: That's because you removed the `-i` parameter from the `sed` command.